# In WKWebKitWebView, how to set global JS variable before page JS executes?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, wkwebview

I have a page that is loaded in both non-embedded and embedded browsers in various operating systems. A non-embedded browser has a cookie from a previous interactive login that allows to access the resources - embedded browsers have to set a global variable that contains an access token, before the embedded browser executes any javascript of the loaded page. (Timing is key.)

I am developing the macOS application, in VisualStudioForMac with Xamarin.Forms. The following code worked as expected for at least three years:

```
const AuthenticationInjectionCode = @"var PAGE_DATA = {BEARER: ""{token}""};"

var token = await accessTokenSource.GetAccessTokenAsync(cancellationToken);
var code = AuthenticationInjectionCode.Replace("{token}", token};
webKitWebView.EvaluateJavaScript(new NSString(code), (result, error) => {
     if (error != null) {
         logger.Error($"Injection of access token failed, error handling gave error: {error.Description}");
     }
});

webKitWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(...)));
```

I have recently updated the development environment to a newer version of MacOS and XCode on the build machine (previously: macOS 10.15; now: macOS 13.3.1), and suddenly, this is no longer working. By commenting out the "LoadRequest" and inspecting elements of the now empty page, I found that the injection works correctly (the global variable is correctly declared), but the `LoadRequest` now seems to be invalidating the pre-existing global variable. I already found `WKContentWorld` for `EvaluateJavaScript` and tried using both `WKContentWorld.Page` and `WKContentWorld.DefaultClient`, but neither did solve the issue.

Any idea what else I can try to get the global variable into the page before the JS is executed?

Comment: Can you show the details about `using both WKContentWorld.Page and WKContentWorld.DefaultClient`? And did you set the [allowsContentJavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebpagepreferences/3552422-allowscontentjavascript) as true`?